# Making Twitter Bootstrap Responsive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a website under development (http://www.snippet-monkey.com). This site was developed with Twitter Bootstrap and Rails3.

Now the layout shows different behavior in different browsers. It works fine on all browsers in my laptop, but fails in other machines and works in many others.

How could i convert this layout to responsive? 
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with 'It works fine on all browsers in my laptop, but fails in other machines and works in many others.'? Responsiveness has nothing to do with machines or browsers (in my opinion) but how your page behaves at certain viewports (aka screen-sizes)

Comment: @Rockbot - Sorry, That's what i exactly meant to say. As platform changes screen sizes may vary.

Comment: Are you using the .less oder .sass/.scss version of bootstrap?

Comment: I am using .css.less pattern of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Add @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

to your bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file

By default these days bootstrap isnt configured to be responsive , you have to add this feature in, this is the simplest way

Comment: Tried this out. But still not working. The "Sign In" button on top right header seems to be invisible as the window size is reduced. Is that because on nav bar fixed top?

Comment: ok so your button disappears as you haven't enabled the responsive layout for the navbar see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar (responsive navbar)

Comment: second thing, get rid of all your inline styling and put it in a  external stylesheet, looks your overriding to much of the default bootstrap behaviour

Comment: Third thing- i would consider going through your HTML and CSS again, and looking into how bootstrap works, design to be responsive not design then make responsive, if you need a hand let me know, however i do like the concept of your site though